# biblatex philosophy autocite multiple sources wrong placement of optional text

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to cite several authors but using the "cf." as a free text

So far I came up with:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose]{biblatex}

% ... 
bla bla\autocites[cf.][376]{PlantingaResponseToAdams}[cf.]{craig1994adams}[and cf.][162-176]{Flint1998}.
```

which results in

[image]

How do I get the "cf." where it should be?

Or is it common to place a "cf." only for the first of the multiple sources?

Comment: Add empty optional arguments if you don't have page numbers: `[cf.][]`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You should make that an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add empty optional arguments if you don't have page numbers: `[cf.][]{craig1994adams}` etc.